# Pandas dataframe and concurrent access by several users

Tags: python, mysql, mongodb, pandas, dataframe

**MY OBJECTIVE :** To read/write values to/from a large table by many users.

My dataframe is a table of size 10000x3000 (approx). They contain integers/float only. They are nothing but stock prices updated every 1/3/5 minutes. Some simple stat calculations are performed and some columns in this table are updated. Rows grow but columns dont.

Till now I used pandas dataframe to perform tasks and finally read/write to CSV files as a means of storage. I was the only user. Now I want to give access to others too. So this dataset needs to handle concurrent access.

**OPTION A :** Many DBMS (MYSQL,MONGODB etc) have these(and many others) features built in and SQLAlchemy/DATASET simplify further.But I think it to be overkill as I have no complex queries to operate. I just pass **[i]**th row and **[j]**th column and fetch/write the corresponding 'value'. Even other users will do the same(read only access).

**OPTION B :** Another idea of mine is a custom server taking in [i][j] and performing read write actions. Will I face any hurdles here ?

So how do I go about making this dataset available to a larger audience ?

Comment: I have no experience with DBMS

Comment: Unless you are certain the scope of what you want to do will never, ever increase, it sounds like you want a dbms. Bite the bullet, it will make your life easier!

Comment: @greg_data : Thanks. I am now leaning towards DBMS. Will explore further.